# How can I do customize category - android

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORVek.png

How can I add category in this way? I tried today until now.
For every category, I want to put items in string array. But I don't know what should search on google for this thing. I guess this is named "spinner".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) is the 'man' for giving custom views to your Spinner.

> Extended Adapter that is the bridge between a Spinner and its data. A
>   spinner adapter allows to define two different views: one that shows
>   the data in the spinner itself and one that shows the data in the drop
>   down list when the spinner is pressed.

In the `getDropDownView`, just return the custom view that you want.

Yes, you are correct. That drop down is called a `Spinner` in Android. If you want a tutorial, have a look at the official docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Yes I found these tutorials. But I want to add category in Spinne,when I selecte one category I want to generate random text from string. This thing I don't know how to do

Comment: Are you looking for [`onItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener))

Comment: So if I have 3 category (geography, biology and history)
how should looks like onItemSelectedListener code?

Comment: On this tutorial I was looking ! Thank you ! I hope will do this thing right.